# GetNativeSystemInfo() and processor groups

Tags: windows, winapi, multiprocessing

Does the dwNumberOfProcessors member of SYSTEM_INFO populated by the GetNativeSystemInfo() function count all logical cores, or only those in the first processor group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetNativeSystemInfo() return information only about the calling process's processor group. :(
but take a look GetLogicalProcessorInformation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like no simple API call to return total nunmber of logical cores?  I have code which builds a CPU topology map, I can query that for the total number logical cores, but man, this seems wrong...